# NGINX HTTP PUT method and Error 409 Conflict

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, http

I am trying to install an NGINX web server which would accept HTTP PUT requests from external source. But every time when I try to put a file on my web server from the external IP I got Error 409 Conflict:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://192.168.178.100/hls/ -d index.m3u8
<html>
<head><title>409 Conflict</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>409 Conflict</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` config is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name 192.168.178.100;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    dav_methods PUT;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? When I upload the files manually I can read them from the http://192.168.178.100/hls/ and the web server is up and running.

And this is my error in the `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
cannot PUT to a collection, client: 192.168.178.50, server: 192.168.178.100, request: "PUT /hls/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.178.100"
```

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 and I haven't installed PHP and MariaDB on it because I don't need them.